# Prove that $T$ is a continuous function of $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ with $p>1$. Define $T(f,a)=f_a$, where $f_a(x)=f(x-a)$. Prove or disprove that $T$ is a continuous function of $a$ .

Claim that $T$ is not continuous. So I want to find an $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that if $|a-b|<\delta$,then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x-a)-f(x-b)|^px\ge\epsilon$. The only function I could think of is the Dirichlet function. But can you prove that it is the function I want?

Comment: No, you are given $f$ from the way this is stated, so you cannot pick $f$.

Comment: $T$ is continuous. To prove this: First, show that $T$ is continuous if $f$ is a step function. Then use the fact that step functions are dense in $L_p$. Note, you need to show $\Vert f_a-f\Vert_p \rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: OP: You would save everybody's time by specifying whether you are interested in the continuity of $T$ (a function defined on $L^p\times\mathbb R$) or in the continuity of $T(f,\ ):a\mapsto T(f,a)$ for a given $f$ in $L^p$.

Comment: I mean the continuity of $T(f, ): a \to T(f,a)$ for a given $f$.

Comment: Presumably you want $p < \infty$ as well. If $f=1_{\{x| x\geq 0 \}}$, then $\|f-f_a\|_\infty = 1$ for all $a \neq 0$.

Comment: For for $p \in [1,\infty)$, another way (similar to David's suggestion above) is to use the fact that smooth, compactly supported functions are dense in $L^p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator \supp {supp} \DeclareMathOperator* \sup {sup}$

1. Let $f \in C_C(\mathbb{R}) := \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; f$ continuous, $\supp f$ compact$\}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ arbritrary and $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\forall z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n, |z_1-z_2| \leq \delta: |f(z_1)-f(z_2)| \leq \varepsilon \tag{1}$$
   Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|a-y| \leq \delta$, then we conclude from (1)
   $$|f(x-a)-f(x-y)| \leq \varepsilon$$ since $$|(x-a)-(x-y)| = |a-y| \leq \delta$$ Moreover, there exists $R>0$ such that $$\forall |x| \geq R: |f(x-a)-f(x-y)| = 0$$ (note  that $R$ does not depend on $\delta$). Therefore $$\|f_a-f_y\|_p^p \leq \varepsilon \cdot R$$ so we have proven that $y \mapsto f_y \in L^p$ is continuous in $a$.
2. Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ (where $p \in [1,\infty)$). Since $C_C(\mathbb{R})$ is dense, there exists $(f^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C_C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f^k \to f$ in $L^p$. We have
   $$\|f^k_y-f_y\|_p = \|f^k-f\|_p$$ hence $$\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} \|f^k_y-f_y\|_p \to 0 \qquad (k \to \infty)$$ (i.e. the sequence converges uniformly). Since we already know that $y \mapsto f^k_y \in L^p$ is continuous (from the first part of this proof) we conclude that $y \mapsto f_y \in L^p$ is continuous (as a uniform limit of continuous functions).